# Why would electron spin of 1 contradict Stern-Gerlach experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-spin

in particle physics we know that electron have a spin of 1/2 (and Lande factor g with value 2).
Why can’t we for example conclude spin 1 and g also 1?

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: A massive particle of spin 1 would be split into three different beams, not two. The electron is known to have mass.

Comment: There were several proposed early conventions for spin quantum numbers and their relationships to state multiplicity. A nice history is Tomonaga’s “The Story Of Spin.” Wrapping one’s head around the valid but rejected representations is a challenging exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result in the Stern-Gerlach experiment is,
that the atom beam is split into *two* beams.
This is explained by the atoms having spin $s=\frac{1}{2}$.
Then there are two possible values of $m_s$: $+\frac{1}{2}$
and $-\frac{1}{2}$.

If the atoms would have spin $s=1$, then there would be
*three* possible values of $m_s$: $+1$, $0$ and $-1$.
And therefore the atom beam would be split into
three beams. But this is not what was observed in the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

The Stern-Gerlach experiment (which has a fascinating history involving cigarettes) is predicated on the observance of clear positional peaks in the scattering of electrons in the presence of a magnetic field. The **number** of such peaks determines the spin of the particle. The distance between peaks determines the magnetic moment through which one can calculate the Lande g-factor.